# Creating TestNG .Bat File

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Im having trouble creating a TestNG .Bat file** (After several tries I have failed to create a successfull Bat file which will in turn execute my TestNG file 'testngSides.xml'.

I wish to execute the testng file: 'testngSides.xml' via a batch file, project structure: 
[image]

I also have dependencies stored within the following location 'm2':
[image]

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I am usually a visual person when it comes to understanding problems but I have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you required to use a .bat file? Have you investigated the TestNG plugin for Eclipse? You can trigger runs that way also... if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry could not write a comment due to lack of reputation. Add dependencies in your POM.xml to run the testing.xml(you will need maven surefire plugin too).Once dependencies are set, build your maven project and run maven test through your .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat file with following content (edit it according to your project):

```
set myProjectpath=”PROJECT_PATH”
cd %myProjectpath%
set classpath=%myProjectpath%\bin;%myProjectpath%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %myProjectpath%\testngSides.xml
```

Let me know if it helps.